# Visualizing $f: \mathbb{C}^2\to \mathbb{C}, (z_1,z_2) \mapsto z_1^2+z_2^2$ and its Hypersurface

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-numbers, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I have difficulties to visualize the graph of the given function $$f:\mathbb{C}^2\to \mathbb{C}, (z_1,z_2) \mapsto z_1^2+z_2^2$$ and the Hypersurface $$ X_0 = \{(z_1,z_2) \in \mathbb{C}^2 \mid z_1^2+z_2^2 = 0\}$$

Apparently the Hypersurface looks like two crossed complex lines. But unfortunately I don't understand how to get to its picture. I have to admit, that I am not too comfortable with complex analysis but i'd really love to catch up.

Could someone help me visualizing it and maybe even show me how to draw the Hypersurface's picture?

I'd really appreciate any help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write the defining polynomial as $(z_1 + iz_2)(z_1 - iz_2) = z_1^2 + z_2^2$, such that you get $X_0 = V(z_1 + iz_2) \cup V(z_1 - iz_2).$

Can you see lines now?

PS.: In case that the notion is not familiar to you, $V(f) = \lbrace (z_1,\dotsc,z_n) \in \mathbb{C}^n \mid f(z_1,\dotsc,z_n) = 0 \rbrace$ is just the zero/vanishing set of some polynomial $f \in \mathbb{C}[T_1,\dotsc,T_n]$.

Comment: awesome! thanks a lot. would you mind helping me in vizualising the corresponding hypersurface? is it a parabola? and if so, how can i get there? if it was $\mathbb{R}^2$ i'd knew $x^2+y^2=0$ is basically the origin but what about $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Comment: Well, I was only talking about the hypersurface. It is given by two complex lines intersected at the origin. Since one cannot really visualize complex geometric objects, one tries to visualize the situation as if it was real valued. In this case we have two equations where the second variable is a multiple of the first one. Thus we have two straight lines. Now both equations are fullfilled for the origin such that this is the point of intersection. To see that the lines are visualized orthogonally, consider the sign of the second variable in the equations.